# From given pdf find $E(X^2)$ , $E(X)$ given and $a$ and $b$ are unknowns.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be random variable with the probability density function

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\ ax^2 & { if \ \ \ 0 < x<1}\\
\ bx^{-4}& \text { if $\ \ \ 1 \le x<\infty$} \\
\end{cases}
$

Where $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers .If $E(X)=1$, then $E(X^2)$ equals___

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=\int_{0}^{1} ax^2dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}bx^{-4}dx=\frac{ax^3}{3}\bigg|_{0}^{1}+\frac{bx^{-3}}{-3}\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}\implies a+b=3---(1)$

$E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)=\int_{0}^{1} ax^3dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}bx^{-3}dx=\frac{ax^4}{4}\bigg|_{0}^{1}+\frac{bx^{-2}}{-2}\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}\implies \frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{2}\implies a+ 2b=4---(1)$

Solving $(1)$and $(2)$ we get $a=2$ and $b=1$

$E(X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)=\int_{0}^{1} ax^4dx+\int_{1}^{\infty}bx^{-2}dx=\frac{ax^5}{5}\bigg|_{0}^{1}+\frac{bx^{-1}}{-1}\bigg|_{1}^{\infty}\implies \frac{a}{5}+{b}\implies \frac{2}{5}+1=\frac{7}{5}=1.4$
Can anyone point out my mistake did I do everything right? My answer key says $3.5$.[image]

Comment: What you have done looks right to me.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you please try for yourself and confirm because of I have to challenge this answer key .

Comment: I did check the calculation and $\frac 7 5 $ is the right answer.